# add pilot light parallel to switch downstream from load

Tags: electrical

**UPDATE:**

I used incorrect nomenclature in a couple places, and I made a couple assumptions that are not wise assumptions to make.  Original answer is below, corrections here.  I'm thinking the question title should probably remain unchanged (mods?).

My specific wiring situation is called a switched loop.  There is no neutral wire in a switched loop. They are "Always-hot" and "Switched-hot"

I'm disappointed there's no UL-listed way to accomplish my original intent--but no more disappointed than I'd be to arrive home and find a fire truck on my lawn.  Thanks to JACK (and especially Harper) for the corrections and alternate ideas.  I'll answer this myself once I decide on and implement a solution.  It's no emergency, so this may be awhile.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I want a (110v) pilot light to indicate my closet light has been left on.

The switch box has only a single of each: hot, neutral, ground--no wirenuts--so it's downstream.  Therefore it seems anything I connect in this box will be wired in series to the light.  Is there a way around this?

---

**DETAIL**

I stole [this image from Joe](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41457/how-do-i-wire-a-switched-outlet-with-the-switch-downstream). It's nearly perfect, but IIRC the lamp fixture also had a ground terminator.

[image: light switch downstream from light]

I want the pilot in the (single gang) wall plate as found in [a review](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1FJA9X97RR8PT/) of [this item](https://smile.amazon.com/Blue-Sea-Systems-120V-Green/dp/B000K2IKPK/), which I've purchased.

[image: 110v switch with small, integrated, aftermarket pilot light]

This little LED has only 26-gauge wire, likely making a series connection an unwise overload risk.  Heat shrink conceals something on one of the leads, and I don't know what it's for.  I suspect it regulates the AC current for directional flow--do LEDs require this?

[image: small 110v LED with heatshrink-wrapped wire]

I've already mounted the LED in a plate, but my final solution doesn't necessarily require this specific LED.  I *do* like the small size and its brightness.

I have several larger, red ones that are not [this specific item](https://smile.amazon.com/Indicator-Replacable-Mounting-Diameter-Diamond/dp/B008KNPP9U/) but look the same to me. I could use one of them if necessary.

[image: large 110v red LED]

My red LED has 18 gauge wire, so I tried wiring one in series.  But the closet light only flickered (far slower than 60-cycles) while the LED indicator turned on.  The housing is easily spacious enough to contain whatever is lurking in the other's heat shrink.  So maybe my directional current hunch is correct, and certain components in each light (indicator and fixture) conflicted, resulting in the flicker.

Both LEDs light up when I just stick them in an outlet, so I assume there's no malfunction with either one.

Finally, I'd rather this look good when finished; it's in my master BR.  While Decora is preferable, I can settle for the traditional style toggle.  I'd prefer to avoid an industrial-looking switch:

[image: functional-but-unattractive illuminated switch]

---

**NOTES**

My closet light switch is outside the closet, and when I'm in a hurry I tend to close the door without remembering to turn off the light.  It's easy to miss until returning at night when the light is visible under the door.

Lately that's happening more frequently, and it's stressful coming home to learn I've wasted ten hours of electricity.  The closet light is an LED, so this is more for principles of efficiency, conservation, and peace of mind than actual money loss.

The closet light is an LED (not incandescent), so it's probably inadvisable to "cheat" and repurpose the ground as neutral--but I'm open to suggestions from someone smarter than I am. The walls and ceiling are finished, so pulling wire would be enough hassle to cancel the project--I'd rather install a pull-chain switch inside the closet and replace the existing wall switch with an in-series jewel light.

I initially sought a manufactured solution, but I'm flummoxed by how many "nightlight" variants are available and yet I can't find a wire-and-go switch **where the indicator turns on *while the load is powered***, even aside the series vs. parallel concern.

I'm confident if both the closet and pilot lights were incandescent they'd work in series--but that seems a step backward after upgrading to more efficient LEDs. Then again, leaving an LED on long enough spends as much money as an incandescent that's always noticeable enough to turn back off when I'm done.  :,/

Several DIY SE questions look very similar but differ, with [this one being the closest](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/134419/adding-a-pilot-light-to-a-light-switch) I've found--his intent similiar to mine.  My initial thought of using a double-pole switch was mistaken--as I'm still downstream from the light--so I'm struggling to conceive a non-series connection.

There's probably enough room in the junction box for a small transformer; if I give up on 110v I might search for a DC LED with a small power supply, rigging that instead.  Of course I'd first leave it plugged in somewhere for a week to ensure it wouldn't overheat.  That seems to be the very-long-way-around solution, but I suppose it'd work.  I expect it would also draw more current than the other solutions, negating its own benefit.

Seems like this should've been a ten-minute-trip-to-Lowes solution, and I've already killed a million brain cells over it.  Thanks in advance for any guidance here.

Comment: Have you considered a motion sensor switch?

Comment: Interesting thought--no I hadn't.  If I go out of town I leave a few lights on for security, and this is one of those.  I'd need to find one that can be locked "on" when necessary.  I'm hoping someone can answer the question, but I like your elegant sidestep of the entire problem.  :,)

Comment: Can you replace the cable from the light to the switch location?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: This is in the corner of my house, where the attic is ~6" high.  It no doubt could be done...however this has already consumed far more of my time than I'll ever recover in electricity savings.  Fishing wire through finished walls while lying prone on insulation, arms outstretched--looking conspicuously NOT like Superman--here's where I concede defeat.

Comment: @JACK, I wanted to mention... your bio is kickass.  You've led an interesting life, thanks for posting that.

Comment: I most certainly get where you're coming from. I _know_ I've seen standard, old-school toggle switches that light up when _on_. However, all they seem to sell these days is ones that light up when _off_ ([for example](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Legrand-radiant-Single-Pole-White-Illuminated-Compatible-with-LED-Rocker-Light-Switch/1000003598)). Have you considered one of those? I accidentally installed one in our bedroom (didn't realize it had the light-up feature when I bought it) and we very quickly learned to ignore the glow at night.

Comment: @FreeMan: Nah. Theoretically growing comfortable with the light on would mean I'd notice something amiss with the light off. Yet I've experienced alarm fatigue in a NOC where Nagios was (over|mis)configured for months until someone cleaned it up. Seeing all those green statuses was wonderful, but it was awhile before we were able to once again take alarms seriously. A *negative alarm* would be guaranteed to affect me worse than that gig did. (PS: thanks for the validation--I actually *have* one purchased years ago at Lowes in my basement, so I know they exist)

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvoted.  Like thousands of other SE questions, It came from a place of ignorance in completing a project--and its author (eventualy) learned something in the process of interacting with those who know better.  It generated a lot of dialogue and has a designated, selected answer.  Can't please 'em all, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your wiring configuration is an old style switch loop, which does not provide neutral.

To stop killing brain cells, stop violating Code. Any solution that violates Code, cross it off immediately: *kill it with fire before it kills you with fire*.   All that stuff you saw in Amazon reviews and Youtube videos are jackasses trying to burn their house down (plus, they weren't on a switch loop like you are).

Also, everything you use must be UL-Listed as equipment for AC mains use in houses.  Not RU-Recognized as components.  Especially, no using random bits you got off Alibaba (Amazon Marketplace is basically Alibaba, so is eBay, Banggood etc.)

### You want this instead

[image]

Get a 5-10 minute one, and get one with a "hold on indefinitely" position if you want that.  You can use the electronic push button variety if you find one that does not need neutral (they are out there).

### A commercial pilot light is right out

The problem is, they all need neutral, and you don't have it on a switch loop.

### The Hail Mary play: low voltage DC/AC

It is perfectly allowable to attach a UL-Listed low voltage power supply to a light, if the light provides a legal wiring method to do that.  For instance many companies make 24 VAC transformers that go in a common round knockout.  From there you qualify for the very much relaxed *low voltage rules* in NEC.  Now you can use /2 thermostat wire to carry 24VAC or other voltage to wherever you see fit to have any kind of an indicator.

There is one gotcha: you cannot intermix or commingle low voltage wires with AC mains wires.  You will note any of the knockout-mounted transformers will provide for the low voltage to be *outside* the knockout. So what is Right Out is to install a low-voltage LED inside the AC junction box.

### Or just go LVDC for the whole kaboodle

Honestly, given the low power requirements of LED lighting and the ready availability of 12/24 VDC LEDs, there's no reason not to just make *the entire lighting branch* low voltage — the closet light, the switch leg, the switch and the indicator.

You need a UL listed power supply in the closet, but after that, you have a great deal of latitude.  (but still not Alibaba).

There is one snag: most consumer switches are not UL-listed for *any* DC voltage.

But here's a wacky idea: use an AC low voltage supply, and use diodes to treat the switch loop as two completely separate loops.  Positive flow, the pilot light is shorted around (by a diode) and the switch is in series with the lighting LED.  Negative flow, the lighting LED is shorted around (by a diode) and the switch is in series with the pilot light.  Add a little capacitance to arrest flicker on the pilot; many DC LEDs already have that built in.

You can reuse the /2+gnd Romex cable for low voltage power, as long as you have partitions inside the junction boxes. Using wire and cable for low voltage that was intended dor AC mains wiring is fine.   It would be a Code violation to use safety ground for ordinary operating current, though.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that??? Oh, it's Monday....  better than a motion sensor.+1

Comment: [The problem is, they all need neutral] I was hoping that wasn't the case--dang.  I was wondering if that was a true neutral (should've listened to that hunch more).  So then what's the term for the non-hot wire in a switch loop?

Comment: I'd hoped I was merely searching the wrong Alibaba pages, and someone makes a lighted switch that can do on or off (bypassing all of my brain damage).  LVDC and the timer are both good ideas; thank you.

Comment: @zedmelon  The 2 wires in a switch loop are "Always-hot" and "Switched-hot".  If neutral is not present, white must be always-hot.   Alibaba is another brain-cell killer.  Remember NEC 110.2, everything must be approved which means UL-Listed.  Nothing from Alibaba is, it is pointless to shop there.  Anything AC mains must be gotten from Home Depot, ACE, City Electric, etc.

Comment: Harper, thanks so much for taking the time for a detailed answer.  And again for the supplemental edgjyimickayshin.  Truly appreciated.  Still deciding on an approach but will update with the result.

Answer (score -6):

ALL of you guys have no clue what you are talking about... fire-risk, code, blah, blah, blah - a 0.5 watt LED is not starting a fire... my Dad (and now I) have wired these 110V AC LED's into many toggle switches around the house, the sheds, etc... If you want it to indicate power to the switch and lights off (like a pilot) then you wire each end of the LED to the poles of the switch... the LED will be dark when lights are on... If you want it to indicate power to the lights when the lights are on (as the OP wants) then you wire one end of the LED to one of the poles of the switch and the other LED wire to one (or both, if they are twisted together) bare copper ground wires, or just ground it to the box...

Comment: Welcome to [DIY.se]. You're getting down votes because this is A) a _bit_ on the rant side and we try to avoid that here, and B) because we don't _ever_ advocate skirting or ignoring code. Unfortunately, large swaths of the NEC were written in blood and are designed to stop people from just doing "whatever" because it's convenient and hasn't hurt me _yet_. _If_ the OP has a 120v rated LED, that might be acceptable (if it's UL listed), but so much stuff isn't listed. You are correct - it's 100% OK to install... until it isn't.

Comment: Adding an LED indicator light to light switch is NOT ignoring or skirting code - see, this is what I mean by "ALL of you guys have no clue what you are talking about..." I don't really care if I am getting "down votes" - it's the correct solution - hopefully, someone who is looking to do exactly what the OP wanted to do will read it and say "oh, I see - easy enough - problem solved!" And you're right, it is a bit of a rant, because namby-pamby "politically correct" fraidy-cats get on here and try to frighten people into not solving their problem, with the "you'll burn down your house" line.

Comment: If you care to edit your post to indicate where in code this is allowed, and/or specific parts that the OP should look for to ensure a code compliant install, I'm sure votes will be reversed. Bear in mind, many people do non-code-compliant things out of ignorance. Getting "authoritative recommendations" to their specific question that may non-compliant is not going to help.  Unfortunately, if someone were to see your advice & follow it, but not do it properly, it could lead to a fire that an insurer could use non-compliance to deny a claim. Worse, lives could be lost. Yes we err to caution.

Comment: How about YOU quote ANY electrical code that specifically does not allow the wiring of supplemental low power indicator lights to a circuit... there are billions of LED indicator lights in use around the world, from industrial, to household, to automotive, to even the "power on" light flashing on your computer or laptop that you are using right now!! I have NEVER heard of ANY instance of any LED causing a fire - IT IS A DIODE - the internals are insulated, and at worst, you would get a faint puff or zapping sound - like a fuse blowing!! But you prefer to scare people with "lives could be lost"

Comment: And... after re-reading your last comment I noticed this: "if someone were to see your advice & follow it, but not do it properly..." - well, then they wouldn't be following my advice, would they? And doesn't that go for EVERYTHING on this site? Even "CODE COMPLIANT" advice? Why are you singling me out for 'people who don't follow the advice properly' leading to 'lives lost?' Isn't every recommendation here done with the implication that the advice given will be followed as given? If not, you better start adding a "lives could be lost if you don't follow directions" comment to every post.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Pilot Indicator: indicates power to the switch when the closet light is not illuminated; the LED indicator will be dark when the closet light is illuminated; the LED indicator will also be dark when no power is flowing to the switch (and the closet light will obviously not be illuminated - power failure/breaker off etc...)

Connections: Wire each end of the LED to the poles of the switch.

Comment: Switch ON Indicator: indicates power to the closet light when the closet light is illuminated (as the OP desired;) the LED indicator will be dark when the closet light is not illuminated.

Connections: Wire one end of the LED to one of the poles of the switch and the other LED wire to one (or both, if they are twisted together) bare copper ground wires, or just ground it to the box or the ground (green) screw on the switch.